# Is there a way to solve different numbers of arguments in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Hello I want to make definition of `plusTree`.

Definition for this.

[image]

```
data Tree = Null | Node Int Tree Tree   deriving Show


plusTree :: Tree -> Tree -> Tree
plusTree Null         ys     = Null
plusTree xs          Null    = Null
plusTree (Node x xs) (Node y ys)  = Node (x+y) (plusTree xs ys)
```

And I create the above code.

> Constructor `Node' should have 3 arguments, but has been given 2
>
> In the pattern: Node x xs
>
> In an equation for `plusTree': plusTree (Node x xs) (Node y ys) = Node
>   (x + y) (interactive:IHaskell544.plusTree xs ys)

Also I got a above error. So I tried with various method. and i finally though it will be work when i add something in 4th argument.

```
plusTree :: Tree -> Tree -> Tree
plusTree Null         ys     = Null
plusTree xs          Null    = Null
plusTree (Node x xs) (Node y ys)(Node z zs)  = Node (x+y+z) (plusTree xs ys zs)
```

Now i got a another error. and also i tried several method again. but can't fixed it.

> 'Equations for `plusTree' have different numbers of arguments'
>
> :2:1-35
>
> :4:1-79

Can somebody give advice or solution to help me? now i'm blocked in the wall.

Comment: It is not complaining about the number of arguments of `plusTree`, but about the number of arguments of the `Node` constructor in your function. `Node` has three parameters, so you should handle nodes like `Node x lx lr`.

Comment: A `Node` is supposed to have two subtrees. One of them is missing in `(Node x xs)`, `(Node y ys)`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler does *not* complain about the number of parameters of the `plusTree` function. It complains about the fact that your `Node` constructor should have three parameters. Indeed:

```
data Tree = Null | Node Int Tree Tree deriving Show
```

Here you thus define a `Node` as a *data constructor* that has three parameters: an `Int`, and two `Tree`s. But in your function, you only write two of these:

```
plusTree (Node x xs) (Node y ys) = Node (x+y) (plusTree xs ys)
```

hence that is not a correct `Node` instance.

I assume that this is some sort of *binary* tree where the second parameter is the *left* subtree, and the third parameter is the *right* subtree. In that case we need to perform double recursion:

```
plusTree :: Tree -> Tree -> Tree
plusTree Null         ys     = Null
plusTree xs          Null    = Null
plusTree (Node x lx rx) (Node y ly ry) = Node (x+y) (plusTree lx ly) (plusTree rx ry)
```

The first clauses define variables `xs` and `ys` that you do not use. In that case, one usually uses an underscore, such that if we turn on all warnings, the compiler will not complain about a variable not used:

```
plusTree :: Tree -> Tree -> Tree
plusTree Null _ = Null
plusTree _ Null = Null
plusTree (Node x lx rx) (Node y ly ry) = Node (x+y) (plusTree lx ly) (plusTree rx ry)
```

Answer (score 4):

the compiler is telling you that you are applying node wrong in this line:

```
plusTree (Node x xs) (Node y ys) = Node (x+y) (plusTree xs ys)
```

because a node takes "Int Tree Tree" and you are trying to match it with "x xs"

oh, and those 2 previous cases are the equivalant of 0+n right?
so shouldn't they be n?

changed code:

```hs
    plusTree :: Tree -> Tree -> Tree
    plusTree Null         ys     = ys
    plusTree xs          Null    = xs
    plusTree (Node x lxTree rxTree) (Node y lyTree ryTree)  = 
        Node (x+y) (plusTree lxTree lyTree) (plusTree rxTree lyTree)
```

Comment: I could see `plusTree` being defined either way. Your suggestion works because `(+)` has an identity element, so you can pretend the `Null` tree is a tree of whatever shape you need, but filled with 0s. A more general function `mappendTree` could work for any tree based on a monoid. The most general case, though, probably needs to just ignore nodes in one tree when there is no corresponding node in the other.